# DropDownList Default Value DISABLED

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am using 2 DropDownList in one page. Based on the Selected Value of the 1st DDL the 2nd DDL will get populated with values from the database. Now I want the default value of the 1st DDL to be something like "Please Select a Category". But i cannot set any Value for it, it will remain disabled, the user can only see it, not choose it, as that value is not valid data. I have written the following code

```
<div>
    Categories :
    <asp:DropDownList ID="drdcatID" runat="server"
          AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="FillBrandID" 
          AppendDataBoundItems="true"></asp:DropDownList><br />
    <br />
    Brands :
    <asp:DropDownList ID="drdbrandID" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    Name: 
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    Item Desc: 
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemDesc" TextMode="MultiLine" 
           Columns="50" Rows="5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    Price:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemPrice" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    Availability :
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemAvl" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="additem" 
         Text="Insert" />
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: How dou you bind the controls to data? Please add the code behind  source code that binds And evaluates the data.

Comment: All you have to do is to make **drdbrandID** disable by default. Then enable it back inside **FillBrandID** event.